# ClassCastException in hibernate and spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have user object is as follow:

public class User implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long userId;

@Column(name="emailId")
private String emailId;

@Column(name="userName")
private String userName;

@Column(name="address")
private String address;

@Column(name="mobNo")
private BigDecimal mobNo;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
private Department department;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "desgId")
private Designation designation;

@Column(name="grpId")
private int grpId ;

@Column(name="userLevel")
private int userLevel ;

@Column(name="upw1")
private String upw1 ;

@Column(name="upw2")
private String upw2 ;

@Column(name="upw3")
private String upw3 ;

@Column(name="createdBy")
private String createdBy ;

@Column(name="creationDate")
private Timestamp creationDate;

@Column(name="loginStatus")
private String loginStatus;

@Column(name="hintId")
private int hintId ;

@Column(name="hintAns")
private String hintAns ;

@Column(name="otp")
private String otp ;
```

and metghod is

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("select u.userName, u.mobNo, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm, "
                    + "u.loginStatus from User u");
    List<User> list=(List<User>)query.list();
    return list;
```

}

I got classCastException

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.common.models.User

can anybody suggest me what i did wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query for a set of different fields, so each row in your result list will be a Java array of Objects (`Object[]`).

You want to query for a single object: `select u from User u`.

(and you leave the job of guessing all the fields to select and joins to make to Hibernate).

Comment: Yeah, Hibernate select all the field from User as well department and designation.Now i want get deptname and designame to display on jsp page. How can i do this?

Comment: Its working for that on jsp page i write (<td><c:out value="${userList.department.deptnm}"/></td>
              <td><c:out value="${userList.designation.desgnm}"/></td>)...Thank you @fdreger